# Averting checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception

First, it is my strong opinion that the terms *checked* vs *unchecked* exceptions are imprecise, as it descriptively misleads who is doing the checking or if the checking is voluntary. Therefore I would be using the following terms in this question, so that people not aware of the difference might chip in an answer:

- Check-mandated exception = checked exception
- Check-not-mandated exception = unchecked exception

**Motivation of Question**:
I feel that the writers of standard Java utilities have committed misguided and inappropriate over-dependence on exceptions. The utility that is of my particular attention is the Integer.parseint(String) utility method.

1. It should not use a *check-not-mandated* exception, because everyone who have used the util knows that the string supplied is often unknown and therefore, we would compel a try block anyway. Therefore, it is not a non-salvageable situation.
2. If the writer of the utility had forced the use of *check-mandated exception*, it still would be inappropriate because since you know that there is a high likelihood of exception, then don't make it an exception. Since by logical reasoning, what you do expect would happen cannot be linguistically called an "exception".
3. Reserve use of any exception for actually critical issues.

**Question**:
If I am to rewrite the utility, to satisfy my annoyance against overuse of exceptions by utility writers, what would be the best way to go around this predicament? That would treat unacceptable string, but satisfying my ideology against the overuse of exceptions.

My immediate thinking to solving it would be

- Integer parse(String, Delegate)

Since Java is debilitated/impoverished by the absence of Delegates in the language, I would have it as

- Integer parse(String value, CallBack unacceptedParseCallback);

Where

```
public interface CallBack<T,S> {
  T mitigate(S value);
}
```

- Callback can be null, but only then would a NumberFormatException thrown if Callback mitigation is needed but not supplied.

However, I doubt my quick-and-dirty solution is the best way of avoiding the use of exceptions. What are the alternative algorithms I could use to solve my ideological disagreement with the over-dependence on exceptions? Before I embark on writing a library of such utilities.

Comment: checked = checked by the compiler, unchecked = not checked by the compiler.  BTW other sub-classes of Throwable are checked.

Comment: I like someone with resolute criticism, therefore: switch to Java 8 already (your delegates like `this::toString`). Though C++ already had a kind of exception, Java applied them. So historically seen, it led away from continuing with error results and allowed exception short-cuts. Go ahead and think on optimal handling. Maybe a topic for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the *Maybe* monad, implemented as the `Optional` interface in Java 8. This is a battle-proven approach which facilitates composition of functions in the face if possible "exceptions" anywhere within the composition chain.

One caveat with the above is that the complete API must support the *Maybe* monad for it to be truly useful.

Answer (score 2):

Checked exceptions are those that happen due to something out of reach from the programmer. A perfect example to show you how useful they are, is making a request over the network. In C# (where checked exceptions don't exist), when you use `HttpClient.Get` to make a request, it might work just fine now, but using it again two minutes later an UNEXPECTED network error may occur and there's nothing you can do about it. So if you're a good programmer, you should always be prepared to handle those unexpected network errors by wrapping the call with a `catch`. C# does not enforce this, Java does, Java forces you to be a responsible programmer.


In the case of `Integer.parseInt`, this should not force you to `catch` errors, because any error that might occur is not unexpected. You can find out if the call will break by simply looking at the `string` you are passing. If I as a programmer, know that I will always be passing a valid `string`, am I seriously supposed to put a `catch` in there I know will NEVER be used?

Comment: If you have read, C#'s approach is actually known as the solution to the problem not the problem to the solution.

Comment: @BlessedGeek that's only a point of view. Elaborate what problem it's trying to solve and how does it solve it.

Comment: It's generally accepted that using exceptions for normal functioning code is bad bad bad practice.

Comment: @BlessedGeek It is also generally accepted that letting your program crash due to a simple network error is bad, bad, bad practice.